# How can I redirect the discharge of my forced air vent?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

An AC/heating register on our kitchen ceiling blows air directly toward a gas cooktop causing the flames to flicker. Adjusting the register doesn't seem to make a difference. I've looked into air deflectors but the ones I've found seem cheap or have bad reviews.

Is there a high quality air deflector out there or, even better, an alternative solution (e.g., a highly adjustable register)?

Here's a photo of a similar register.
[image]

Comment: Is this a ceiling, wall, or floor-mounted register? A picture might help.

Comment: Ceiling. I don't have time at the moment to take a photo, but I've added one to my question that looks exactly the same.

Comment: Does this cause a problem when you're actually cooking something (there is a pot or pan over the flames?) You would think that the cooking vessel shields the flames. If the air flow is not actually blowing out the flames, it might not be a problem, just a psychological annoyance when you're lighting the range.

Comment: It doesn't blow the flames out. But it also cools food sitting on the counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get (or fabricate) a register deflector.
[image: register delector]

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, most of the ones I've found are cheaply made. After initially "installing" one of these I accidentally bumped it and it shattered. I found a better one later and it's working well so far. I asked the question hoping to learn if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to take the register off and place a Air damper in the vent. Then Then set the damper to a fixed point( as to not blow the flames).

This can be a bit tricky to place inside the ceiling though.

another option would be to take off the vent, and place duct tape(solution for everything) on the inside of the vent where it is blowing toward you flame. IF you are concerned about building code, then it would be better to get a non flammable tape. Your not suppose to have anything flammable in the air duct system.

Answer (score 0):

Which vents point toward the stove?  (I'm assuming your actual register has the same arrangement of vents as your photo; if not, please disregard...)

If it's the center/largest set of vents - the ones pointing downward in the picture - then I'd say that the easiest thing would be to rotate the register 180° so that those vents are blowing away from the stove.

If it's one of the sides, this doesn't help, of course.